# Is it possible truncate excerpt with DOM atributtes? HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, rest, truncate

I have tried to shorten excerpt from Wordpress REST API, I've tried **maxLength** HTML attribute, but it does not work.

```
<p
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: excerpt.rendered }}
  maxLength={10}
/>
```

Is there any way I can handle it within JS/React?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `paragraph` doesn't have a `maxlength` attribute. If `excerpt.render` is a string and you're just trying to use a substring then I'd just use the `String.substring` method

Comment: Now, I see...but still I don't have a solution...
The problem is I cannot go and edit this in the backend, I must find a way to make it in Frontend.

Thanks

Comment: Again, you could technically grab whatever you need inside the paragraph and just use the `Strinb.substring` method to shorten it. I am assuming it's just some text that goes into that paragraph, so that should be easy.

Comment: I've made it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your question hardly has anything to do with React, it's more about [html](/questions/tagged/html).

HTML's `maxlength` attribute [is applicable only to `input` and `textarea` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength), this way it will do nothing when applied to `p` tag.

HTML doesn't have anything similar for `p` natively, so, a custom implementation is needed. You obviously could do:

```js
'Long text of the article that is going to be shortened'.slice(0, 9).concat('…')
```

which would produce `Long text…`.
However, since you use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, I guess that `excerpt.rendered` contains HTML tags, so, you can't just slice it.

In this case, the easiest option would be to have 2 strings:

1. One containing ready-to-use markup.
2. One containing just text content.

If it's not an option, you may try to parse HTML & extract only text content (be cautious, it might produce unexpected results):

```js
const parsedExcerpt = new DOMParser().parseFromString(excerpt.rendered, 'text/html');
const excerptText = parsedExcerpt.body.innerText.trim();
```

Now you could use `excerptText.slice(0, 9).concat('…')` (more or less) safely.